# Google Chrome Option+Left Arrow does not move cursor back one word in URL bar on MacOS With Unicode Hex Input

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

When you have a url like https://example.com/with/many/parts-in-the/url.do?separated=by&non-word-characters, in Ubuntu and in Windows, chrome will let you navigate through each word separately, if you hold ctrl while pressing the left and right arrow keys.

On MacOS however, my only option is to delete words from the end one by one, with Option + Backspace. Is there any workaround?

Comment: I just tested this on my MacBook, and was able to navigate a URL by word using Option+ArrowKey (left and right). This is the same functionality as using Ctrl+ArrowKey on Windows. Using Alt+ArrowKey on Windows produces the Back/Forward function in the browser. Here are all the shortcuts for Chrome: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Ctab-window-shortcuts

Comment: @JimDiroffII - you're right, ive fixed my question, but it doesn't change what i see in both my macos computers (they are configured similarly to be fair) - hopefully enough other people have had issues with their option+left shortcut for there to be a known fix for it